# Clear all LIST <> each time click the button?

Tags: c#, listbox

Is there any way to clear all the list items in short way instead using List.Clear(); method for each of them? Because when I click my button first time I stored some items inside my list and when I click my button second time it suppose to get new items, but it still holding the old items not the new ones... I think clearing all the list right after click the button and start storing items inside my list would help me to get solved this problem...

I have below classes:

```
Fruits
vegetables
cars
Homes
.
.
.
```

Comment: maybe clear each list before you refill it?

Comment: If they are in different classes then this will be very difficult...

Comment: @TimSchmelter somehow it still holding the old ones. when I click the button second time.

Comment: @iabbott I supposed to clear them inside each classes?

Comment: If they are all in the same form or even the same container control like `Panel` you could use `foreach(var lb in Controls.OfType<ListBox>()) lb.Items.Clear();`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Post that as an asnwer

Comment: @TimSchmelter the question says they are in different classes

Comment: @TimSchmelter I dont have list boxes. I have LIST<>

Comment: @user2760129 if they are in different classes then yes you should clear them in their own classes.

Comment: @user2760129: `List<of what>`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter LIST<string>

Comment: What is the relationship of each of those classes to the form with the button on it?  Are they worker classes that the form creates to do work?  Are they in child forms, parent forms, or what?

Comment: @Servy well I am using each of the LIST <string> to store different values inside each classes. and calling this classes inside my button.

Comment: @user2760129 So you're creating each of these twelve class instances in the button click event?  If so, what kind of action are they doing?  Why is the data persisting for so long that it needs to be cleared?  Are you holding onto the instances as fields?

Comment: @user2760129 Because you didn't include enough information in the question for it to be answered, like for example including enough of your code to actually see what's going on.

Comment: @Servy ok I will edit my question than

Comment: @Servy I updated. Hope it helps.

Comment: @user2760129 It does; the question is now answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are all private lists you will not be able to see them from another class

Even if you made them `public static` you would still have to do:

```
Class1.myLIST1.Clear();
Class2.myLIST2.Clear();
// etc
```

Comment: This may not be feasible, and if it were, it would almost certainly be a completely inappropriate solution to use.  They may very well be multiple instances of the same class, or there may be other instances not tied to this particular form, etc.

Comment: @Servy please give a better solution then...From the question *each of the list stored inside different classes* and each is `private static`. I didn't say this was the best way of doing what he needed to do, I suggested a way for him to do what he is asking

Comment: @iabbott A proper solution to the problem isn't possible given the information provided, thus the proper approach is to wait for sufficient information, not to provide inappropriate and irresponsible solutions.

Comment: @user2760129 That's an improper mindset.  Giving someone an inappropriate solution to a problem is *harmful*.  They'll waste time trying to get an improper solution working.  Worse still, a solution like this may appear to work in a few test cases despite but continue to cause significant problems down the road as it's not addressing the underlying design issues.  As a result of the code the OP has shown, it's clear that this is *not* a good solution, and that there should be no static lists in the first place.  Fixing that problem makes the whole issue go away.

Comment: @iabbott it was my fault not your that why you get +1. :)

Comment: @user2760129 It's only going to cause more grief for you if you try to maintain this model going forward.  I *strongly* suggest you not use this particular programming practice, because the problem that you're currently having is really the least of your concerns as the complexity of your application rises.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your problem is simply to not have the lists in the first place.

Rather than having these static methods be `void` and sticking their results in static lists that need to be cleared each time they are called, you should instead have then return their values, like so:

```
public static List<string> GetFruits()
{   
    var list = new List<string>();

    OracleConnection conn1 = MyConnection.GetSourceConnection();

    conn1.Open();  
    using (OracleCommand storeFruits = new OracleCommand("MyCOMMAND", conn1))
    {
        using (OracleDataReader reader = storeFruits.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                list.Add((string)reader["TABLE_NAME"]);
            }
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

This has a number of advantages:

1. You can call the method concurrently without any concerns, since each caller has their own list.
2. There is no worry about clearing the lists, ever.  You start fresh every time.
3. There is no worry about a list that one caller is using being modified as a result of some other call in some other location.  Each caller only needs to worry about their code, not everyone else's.

Comment: Well I think this is the answer, but I need to check before accept.Thanks

Comment: Please check my question. the last one

Comment: @user2760129 If you want to return more than one value create a new type that represents what you want to return, and then return a new instance of that.  Create a new class that has two `List<string>` properties, and return those.  The other option is that rather than two lists of strings you should have one list of a custom type that has two string properties, if the values of the two lists together form a single item.  I couldn't say which makes sense to you without  knowing what the specific data is.

Comment: idea is compering the data that stored inside my LIST1 and LIST2.... and creating new List depends on the compered result.